# How to pass in props to an element that changes in size depending on prop

Tags: reactjs

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around props. I'd like to use a card shape in different components, and it be resized depending on which component it's in. For instance, if it's in a component at the bottom of the page, it will be big-sized; if in a component at the top of the page, then small-sized. I hope this makes sense. I just have the following code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Card = () => {
  return (
    <div className='card'>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card;
```

I don't know where to put the props and how I would go about to pass them in, I really need it dumbed down for me, maybe an example. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on parent component pass your props

`<Card ComponentA={true) ComponentB={false}/>`

or simply

`<Card ComponentA/>`

on Card component

```
const Card = ({ComponentA}) => {
  return (
    <div className={ComponentA ? "big-card" : "small-card"}>
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

you can also use props this way if you prefer

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.ComponentA ? "big-card" : "small-card"}>
        
    </div>
  )
}
```